# See the contents of Checkpoint files?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Per [documentation](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring), variables in a session can be saved and restored to/from a binary file with `tf.train.Saver` object.

But is there any way to see the content of the binary file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A checkpoint file is an sstable. The value for each record is a serialized
`SavedTensorSlices` message. (resource [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9c3043ff3bf31a6a81810b4ce9e87ef936f1f529/tensorflow/core/util/saved_tensor_slice.proto#L4))

To see the content of the serialized `SavedTensorSlices` message, we just unerialize the content into a `SavedTensorSlices` object. Something like below:

```cpp
SavedTensorSlices message;
message.ParseFromString(value);
cout << message.DebugString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The files are read/written using [TensorSliceReader](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9c3043ff3bf31a6a81810b4ce9e87ef936f1f529/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc) and [TensorSliceWriter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9c3043ff3bf31a6a81810b4ce9e87ef936f1f529/tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_writer.h) in C++ using what seems to be a special format for tensor data.

The files contain the values of the saved tensors. The simplest way to inspect those values would be to restore the tensors from the checkpoint file and inspect the tensors directly.